# Codeigniter 3 404 Page Not Found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have uploaded a codeIgniter 3 application from local to server setting up following files:

File .config

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.myswebsite.com/project';
```

File .routes

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'projects';
```

File .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

When I go to the mainController projects I can see the page, but after the login (the page requires a login) I get following error: 
**404 Page Not Found**
URL: www.mywebsite.come/project/login
I cannot understand the reason...

Comment: I found the problem. The login controller was written in lowercase (login) instead of uppercase (Login).

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem but I overcame this by doing such a way

Enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2 or latter. To do so, create .htaccess file in your root project directory. Add the code bellow in your file and save it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /projectname/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Other important thinks keep in mind :

Controller file name and class name first letter must be upper case.

Example :

file name: Test.php but not test.php

class name: class Test extends CI_Controller {} but not class test ...

Read the link carefully to understand more better:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Note : URL must not contain any uppercase letters. All should be small letter.

Example :

correct
www.projectname.com/test/some_method

incorrect
www.projectName.com/Test/someMethod

I hope you will be remedy from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check Controller class name it should be capitalized letter. first character should be capital

Answer (score 0):

You might need to redirect to `projects` not `project` controller.